# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). &

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'signal':

```
    coresym open_orders direction
27  EURUSD  2.0         1.0
76  XAUUSD  2.0         9.0
```

As I need some condition to set up my '_exec_dict' which is a dictionary to tell the trading platform what my order is?

```
for symbol in do_symbols:
    #close positon
    if ((signal['coresym']==symbol) & (signal['direction'] == 9)):
        _exec_dict['_action'] = 'CLOSE'
        _exec_dict['_symbol'] = symbol
        _exec_dict['_magic'] = symbols_magic_dic[symbol]
        _ret = self._execution._execute_(_exec_dict)
        print('{} is traded'.format(symbol))
```

The problem is I cannot use

```
if ((signal['coresym']==symbol) & (signal['direction'] == 9)):
```

to do the condition determination.

To do the testing:

```
if((signal['coresym']=='XAUUSD') & (signal['direction'] == 9)):
    print('ok')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-f0dcc93290aa> in <module>
----> 1 if((signal['coresym']=='XAUUSD') & (signal['direction'] == 9)):
      2     print('ok')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476 
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1478         raise ValueError(
   1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

to have some alternation,

```
if signal[signal['coresym'] == 'XAUUSD']['direction'] == 9:
       print('ok')
```

the result is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-67440d7a0b81> in <module>
----> 1 if signal[signal['coresym'] == 'XAUUSD']['direction'] == 9:
      2     print('ok')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476 
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1478         raise ValueError(
   1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

After searching, like [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o;)
I do use the '&'.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `if`?

Comment: May I ask what is the better way? As I need the condition to tell what the _exec_dict is going to be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` is not the problem.

`if((signal['coresym']=='XAUUSD') & (signal['direction'] == 9)): print('ok')`

do you nean to say if **all** the elements of `signal['coresym']` are equal to `XAUUSD` and **all** the elements of `signal['direction']` are `=9`.

Or do you mean if `any` of them.

This is the ambiguity that the error describes.

use `all()` or `any()` around your predcats. for example:

`if((signal['coresym']=='XAUUSD').all() & (signal['direction'] == 9).all()): print('ok')`